# QT for beginners

Tags: qt

everybody, I'm beginner in programming, I've just finished my course on C++, I want to train my skills and try to write some programs on C++ with graphic windows (not console programs, I did it during all my course), I want to start working with QT, is it good idea, or I need to begin with something simplier, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt is, among other things, a great framework for developing applications with GUIs.  The only way to know if it is appropriate is to try it out.  I suggest going through [this Qt tutorial](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/tutorial.html), which involves creating a simple game.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with Qt is an excellent idea. Qt is already simpler.

You should begin with these official tutorials: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/tutorials.html

Comment: Actually, most probably you might have 4.6 version of Qt. In that case: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/tutorials.html

Comment: And You might want to read this article on QtCenter that can help you in beginning with Qt4: http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Programming_in_Qt4_and_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 0):

GUI program is a big change from a console app - the difference is that you don't know when things are going to happen and in what order.

But Qt is a very good place to start, the signal/slot mechanism is much clearer (IMHO) than the hidden macros of MFC or some other gui toolkits.